# In NS3 how measure throughput on bridge nodes?

Tags: tcp, udp, tcpclient, ns-3

The question asks to create a simple dumbbell topology, two client Node1 and Node2 on the left side of the dumbbell and server nodes Node3 and Node4 on the right side of the dumbbell. Let Node5 and Node6 form the bridge of the dumbbell.
We have to use point to point links. Next the question asks to install a TCP socket instance on Node1 that will connect to Node3 and to install a UDP socket instance on Node2 that will connect to Node4. We can use UdpSocketFactory.
Starting the TCP application at time 1 and UDP application at time
20s at rate Rate1 such that it clogs half the dumbbell bridge's link capacity.
When we increase the UDP application's rate at time 30s to rate Rate2 such that
it clogs the whole of the dumbbell bridge's capacity.

Comment: Any coding solution is highly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very similar examples to the one you described in `ns-3.29/src/traffic-control/examples`, such as `pfifo-vs-red.cc`, which uses `PointToPointDumbbellHelper` to generate the topology you mention.